# Wpf Tab on mouse Over hover effect

Tags: wpf

[How to change TabItem's Header font without changing content's font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753335/how-to-change-tabitems-header-font-without-changing-contents-font)

I Followed this thread to reduce the size of fonts of my tab in wpf. But now when i move mouse over them it doesnt show any kind of hover effect. I am using MahApps as well.